# SSMS (2012) limit # of characters on editor window line

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

Is there a way to enforce a hard limit on the number of characters allowed on a line in the SSMS editor window? I have searched, but am unable to find an option to set this.

I'd like to force the line to wrap at 100 characters if possible.

Alternately, is there a way to set a visible cue at 100 characters (similar to Vim's colorcolumn setting)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSMS isn't as full-featured as some other editors out there when it comes to visual formatting. I think the closest you'll get is using word wrap from `Tools -> Options`  and then manually sizing your SSMS window to  force it to a smaller column width.

[image]

The bottom row of SSMS will tell you what column number your cursor is on, which may be helpful to size your window to approximately 100 columns wide.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I'm not aware of limiting characters but you have the option to enable word wrap for SQL Server Management Studio

**Tools-->Options-->Text Editor-->All Languages-->Settings - Check Word Wrap**

[image]